# Wrong element position in Google Chrome DevTools

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have HTML markup like this:

```
<div id="renderer-selection">
  <div class="renderer-selection-box">
    <div class="handle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With styles like this:

```
#renderer-selection {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(200px, 200px);
}
.renderer-selection-box {
  position: absolute;
/*  transform: translate(0, 0); */
}
.handle {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.handle::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 5px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #2FA5E7;
}
```

The issue is incorrect element position when using inspect tool in Google Chrome:
[image]

When I'm uncommenting empty transform in styles, inspect position becomes rendering right.
This behavior appeared since one or two last browser updates.
What's cause of this issue? Can someone please explain the meaning of this behavior.

[All related code here on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7trasxne/3/)

Answer (score 0):

it's because your using transform
you can use
this will work better:

```css
#renderer-selection {
  position: absolute;
 /* transform: translate(200px, 200px); */
top: 200px;
 left: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Why transform is causing this unexpected shift? And why it is not breaking devtools in Chrome 92 and earlier?